# Google Places Autocomplete - Clarification on content locale

Tags: api, google-maps

I have a question regarding the content locale of the Google Places API. In my application, we use Places Autocomplete, and when user chose the specific place, we then use Places Detail API to fetch the information 
about the place. Please note, that i've not restricted the places "type" in autocomplete.

Consider this example, "Grant Hyatt Hong Kong"  the places autocomplete returns the suggestion. The suggestion has the Place ID as "ChIJ7VpqmF4ABDQRi1SbdlsRfys"

Using the place detail API, https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ7VpqmF4ABDQRi1SbdlsRfys&key=&language=en, the content has information in english and chinese.

```
    --------------------------

        "address_components" : [
                 {
                    "long_name" : "灣仔",
                    "short_name" : "灣仔",
                    "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
                  .................
                  .................
          "name" : "Grand Hyatt Hong Kong",
              },
    --------------------------------
```

However, when i perform the search using Geocode API, 
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Grand%20Hyatt%20Hong%20Kong,%20hong%20kong, i get the content completely in english. I notice that the Places ID returned in this case, is different from the Places API autocomplete service.

Clearly, the google's database has the information about this place in english. As per the places documentation, the google place API, attempts to return information in the requested locale. In this case, the google's database has the information in english locale.

Why is this difference in the case of Places API?

Answer (score 0):

I can address only one part of your question. Why Geocoding API and Places API search return different results?

Geocoding API doesn't take into account any business, so the result that you get is a different object with place ID ChIJUzElmV4ABDQRyXzjJRwo3VE. This is a compound building that Geocoding API can localize and you can see this building in Map Maker:

https://mapmaker.google.com/mapmaker?gw=90&iwloc=0_0&dtab=history&cid=5898915188285078729

Places API can find a business with place ID ChIJ7VpqmF4ABDQRi1SbdlsRfys. You can see the corresponding feature with the category Hotel in Map Maker:

https://mapmaker.google.com/mapmaker?gw=90&iwloc=0_0&dtab=history&cid=3134242950202741899

Referring to translations, I believe you should raise this issue with Google data team.

Please use the "Report a problem" link on the bottom right corner of the maps.google.com as specified in:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/162873

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will report the issue as suggested.